# tab bar icon selected image

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

How to customize the selected image/icon on the tab bar? Is this possible?

Pls advise. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Its possible without adding any subView.

In the class where you define the tab bar set the property of the 
tabBarItem to ->>

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [[self.tabBar.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:0];
[tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"campaigns_hover.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"campaigns.png"]];
```

Its a property of tabBarItem and u can change the default blue image to a custom image.
campaigns_hover.png is the selected custom image AND
campaigns.png is the custom image when not selected...

Enjoy the secret.. :)

Comment: finishedSelectedImage: is deprecated since iOS 7. Use the selectedImage property instead.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 6 I have change the selected Tabbaritem image like -

In the Tabbar controller delegate method

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

{
    if([tabBarController selectedIndex] == 0)
    {
        [viewController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"]withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselect.png"]];
    }    
}
```

through this you can change your image.

Or you can use directly in your view controllers init(or ViewWillAppear) method, like

```
[viewController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"]withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselect.png"]];
```

Answer (score -4):

You can change the image, but the selected image always has the same blue overlay applied to the image.  The only way I can see getting around this might be to subclass UITabBarItem.

Answer (score -6):

Yes. Just read the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW1)

You can do by IB or code