# iOS 7 change tabBar selected icon

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbar, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I've created a tabBar in storyboard and set a custom image. I want to use a different image for the "selected" state, I know I can't set that image using storyboard but how do I do it programmatically?

I also want to change the icon tint colour in code but can't make that happen either.

I would significantly appreciate any help please.

Comment: This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030741/tab-bar-icon-selected-image

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you `AppDelegate.m` file

```
[tbc.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE_NAME.png"]];
```

where `tbc` - you TabBarController

```
UIStoryboard *iPhoneSB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    CustomTabBarController *tbc = [iPhoneSB instantiateInitialViewController];
```